# Heterogeneity of Contour plot

Tags: plotting

```
u[x_, y_] = x^.5 y^.5;
r[x_, y_] = .2 x + .4 y;
contour1 = 
  ContourPlot[{u[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Axes -> False, Contours -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.3], 
      RGBColor[0.8, 0.9, 1]}, {Opacity[.8], 
      RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]}}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Red], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True];
contour2 = 
  ContourPlot[{r[x, y]}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
   Axes -> False, Contours -> 15, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
   ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.3], 
      RGBColor[0.8, 0.9, 1]}, {Opacity[.8], 
      RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]}}, ContourStyle -> Directive[Red], 
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True];
```

Gives

[image]

With  `Contour` and `ContourStyle` one can decide of the number and style of contours. Now, I want to decide where they are set and change decide a specific style for each contour. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Sure, it's described in the docs for [`Contours`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Contours.html) and [`ContourStyle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourStyle.html)

Comment: Ok I miss the point but what is not said is how to associate a specific contour with a style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OP's second example, one can specify the setting for `Contours` to override the styles set by `ContourStyle`:

```
ContourPlot[.2 x + .4 y, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 Axes -> False, ContourStyle -> Red, 
 Contours -> {{.3, Thick}, {.4, Dashed}, {.2, 
    Directive[Orange, Thickness[.02]]}, ## & @@ Range[0., 2., .05]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 ContourShading -> {{Opacity[.3], 
    RGBColor[0.8, 0.9, 1]}, {Opacity[.8], RGBColor[0.87, 0.94, 1]}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]